# Unique solution to $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $\ k\ $ be a positive integer and $\ \pi(n)$ the number of primes not exceeding $\ n\ $ (The prime counting function).

> Is the solution $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=k$ unique only for $\ k=11$ ?

It is known that there is a solution for every integer $\ k>1\ $.

In OEIS [A038627](https://oeis.org/A038627), the number of solutions is listed upto $\ k=50\ $ and there is only one $\ 1\ $ in this list. Any ideas or reference whether $\ k=11\ $ is actually the only case?

Comment: I tried it on Wolfram Alpha, but it's just keeping away from talking of any solution.

Comment: Well $k\mid n$ so maybe that helps ...

Comment: The OEIS link contains a reference to a paper from 2009 that asks the same question about $11$. See https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Harger-CMJ0911911.pdf

Comment: The first place I would look if I was able to would be the original paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/2312732 . Unfortunately, it's behind a pay wall so I can't access it

Comment: @QC_QAOA, I think jstor has some option for limited free access for independent researchers; you might look into that. But also, the fact that a paper from 47 years later ends by asking if $11$ is the only number for which there's a unique solution would seem to indicate it's a tough nut to crack.

Comment: It is unlikely that a paper would give significantly more insight. Maybe, a few more terms could be determined considering that exact pi-values could be determined for $10^{28}$. If they would already give a second $k$ , OK. But if not, it will be very difficult to show that there is no other $k$ doing the job. We can however estimate the chance to find such another $k$ by analyzing the necessary prime-gap behaviour.

Comment: The solution is unique if and only if the following is true : Let $s$ be the smallest solution of $$\frac{s}{\pi(s)}=k$$ ($k\ge 2$). Then, for every positive integer $m$, there are less than $m$ primes in the range $[s,s+km]$